# In King of Tokyo advanced play, does the monster in Tokyo Bay move into Tokyo City if the Tokyo City monster yields?

Tags: king-of-tokyo

Then the attacking monster would enter Tokyo Bay unless both spots are yielded and attacker enters Tokyo City?  This is important because when monsters are eliminated and there become fewer than 5 players, the rules state that the monster in Tokyo Bay vacates their position leaving only Tokyo City occupied, so the exact location of a monster in Tokyo becomes relevant at that point.

The rules state

> After a Monster that is not in Tokyo attacks, it must take control of Tokyo if either Tokyo City or Tokyo Bay are unoccupied or abandoned. If there is a choice, Tokyo City must be occupied first.

If Tokyo Bay monster doesn't take over, then there could be a scenario where the monster in Tokyo City dies because of a card leaving only 4 players and the monster in Tokyo Bay would be forced to leave, leaving Tokyo unoccupied.

Again quoting the rules

> If a Monster is eliminated and that
>   brings the number of Monsters
>   below 5, Tokyo Bay can't be occu
>   pied anymore. The Monster in it
>   must leave Tokyo.

It seems to make more sense that Tokyo Bay monster would move to Tokyo City, but it is not spelled out.

Comment: It is spelled out. "The Monster in it must leave Tokyo." That's very different than "The Monster in Tokyo Bay must move to Tokyo City if it's free or leave Tokyo otherwise."

Answer (score 6):

**No, Monsters do not move from Tokyo Bay to Tokyo City.**

In a 5-player game, there are multiple possible outcomes when you are attacking Tokyo City and Tokyo Bay.

- **If neither Monster dies** - The attacker occupies Tokyo City , since you are still playing 5-player. The Monster in Tokyo Bay can choose to yield or not.
- **If the Monster in Tokyo City dies** - The attacker occupies Tokyo City, and the Monster in Tokyo Bay must leave per the rule you quoted above, because there are now only 4 players.
- **If the Monster in Tokyo Bay dies** - The attacker occupies Tokyo City if the Monster in Tokyo City yields.
- **If both Monsters die** - The attacker occupies Tokyo City , since you are still playing 3-player. Neither Monster can choose to yield, because they are dead.

Comment: That also means if the Monster in TC dies by means other than attack, and this brings the number of players to 4, the Monster in TB musts leave.

Answer (score 0):

No, if a monster yields, the attacker assumes that monster place.

In case you are playing with more than 4 players and both TC (Tokyo City) and TB (Tokyo Bay) are occupied, these are the possible outcomes:

- **Only TB yields**: The attacker moves to TB
- **Only TC yields**: The attacker moves to TC
- **Both TC & TB yield**: The attacker moves to TC
- **Neither yield or die**: Nothing happens
- **TB dies***: The attacker moves to TB
- **TB dies and TC yields**: The attacker moves to TC
- **TC dies****: The attacker moves to TC
- **TC dies and TB yields**: The attacker moves to TC
- **Both die**: The attacker moves to TC

* *In case the resulting number of players would be lower than 5, the attacker would not move to TB*

** *In case the resulting number of players would be lower than 5, the monster in TB (if any) drops out of Tokyo*